# How to find a line of code in my publicHTML

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I am trying to find a line of code in my public html cpanel. I am trying to search for this line of code in one of my wordpress template. Is there any tool in Cpanel to search for this line of code? Grep command?

```
<div id="masthead-sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper" style="height: 110.787px; min-height: 312px;"><header id="masthead" class="site-header">
```

I can't even change the min-height using Customised CSS since they have hard code to the html file.

Comment: This is not going to be in a file. This is most likely added using JavaScript after the HTML has been rendered. And yes, you can change the `min-height`, just use `min-height: value !important`. `!important` will override any inline CSS styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any FTP program such as FileZila. Connect to your FTP Server, download all files and open this project in Web IDE such as PhpStorm. In this IDE you can search!

if it's util, vote up!

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the built-in editor in cPanel, the shortcut to search code in an individual file is:

```
Control + F
```

If you are referring to searching the entire codebase for a file containing a line of code, I don’t believe this is possible using the cPanel search bar.

According to this cPanel support page, it is possible using SSH and a grep command.

```
grep $search-term /home/$username/public_html/file.php
```

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-to-find-a-line-of-code.446762/

Answer (score 0):

You can zip your files in cpanel and download them to your PC. After you can open the folder with Visual Studio and find the line.